# React native how to Animate Text and Image

Tags: react-native, animation

Hi everyone I just want to animate text and image. This code I wrote is animating at the beginnig.When I update the state, animation is gone just changing image and text. How can I fix it.

```
//the package I installed from npm
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

//the images array changes by state
var arr=[{image:require('./assets/img1.png')},{image:require('./assets/img2.png')},{image:require('./assets/img3.png')}];

//The initial state
state = { 
  uri: require('./assets/img1.png'),
  message:"-",
  img_rank:0
};
```

```
//In onpress method of TocuhableOpacity
<TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

//state of message
this.setState({ message: "Act1" });

//state of image rank from the array
this.setState({ img_rank: randomIndex })
    ...
```

Showing the text and image

```
//it's showing the image with animation at the beginning
<Animatable.Image source={arr[this.state.img_rank].image}  animation="zoomInUp">      
</Animatable.Image>

//the text but it's not animating

<Animatable.Text   animation="zoomInUp">
   <Text>{this.state.message} </Text>
</Animatable.Text>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone how to animate

Comment: I really need this

Comment: Can you elaborate about the type of animation you're looking for? It's not clear to me what you actually want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get your animated component's ref into a variable in your class like **animatedImageRef**.

```
<Animatable.Image 
   ref={r => this.animatedImageRef = r}
   source={arr[this.state.img_rank].image}  
   animation={this.state.img_rank ? 'zoomInUp' : undefined}>      
</Animatable.Image>
```

Then, in your `onPress` function, use this ref to animate your component again.

```
this.animatedImageRef.startAnimation(500, 0, () => { })
```

Comment: What is the ref and r value

Comment: the function we gave to ref is a callback that assign animatable.image 's reference to this. animatedImageRef so the component's methods are easily accessed imperatively by anywhere else.